# Magento Email not included header and footer

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I use community magento 1.9.1.0
All emails sent from the store without the included header and footer, instead, is the code the same as in the template:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}} 
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
```

I checked the file header.html and footer.html in the directory:
app/locale/en_US/template/email/html
and are there.
where should I look for error?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do an update via shell ./mage upgrade-all or via magento connect.

I had magento 1.9.0.1 with the same problem. I upgraded via shell to 1.9.1.0 and the email header/footer issue was fixed!

You should now see an options for Email Header Template, Email Footer Template and Non-inline CSS File(s) under Design > Transactional Emails.